# Como criar um processo interminável?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, cmd

Pergunta simples, como eu faço para o meu processo do aplicativo ser "imparável" pelo sistema? Quero que quando um usuário tenta fechar o aplicativo apareça a mensagem "Acesso negado", e quando força a finalização da o erro no kernel CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED. Isso é o que acontece com o processo `wininit.exe` pelo CMD:

```
C:\> taskkill /im wininit.exe
ERRO: o processo "wininit.exe" com PID 532 não pôde ser finalizado.
Razão: Acesso negado.
```

Nem sequer o processo WinInit é exibido no gerenciador de tarefas. Tem como programaticamente fazer o aplicativo poder fechar sem problemas e outra hora ser interminável?

Answer (score 2):

Achei essa classe em outra pergunta do SO:

```vb
Public Class CriticalProcessInformationProcessor
    <DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function NtSetInformationProcess(hProcess As IntPtr, processInformationClass As Integer, ByRef processInformation As Integer, processInformationLength As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
    Public Shared Sub EnableCriticalProcess()
        Dim isCritical As Integer = 1
        ' we want this to be a Critical Process
        Dim BreakOnTermination As Integer = &H1D
        ' value for BreakOnTermination (flag)
        Process.EnterDebugMode()
        'acquire Debug Privileges
        ' setting the BreakOnTermination = 1 for the current process
        NtSetInformationProcess(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, BreakOnTermination, isCritical, 4)
    End Sub
    Public Shared Sub DisableCriticalProcess()
        Dim isCritical As Integer = 0
        ' we want this to be a Critical Process
        Dim BreakOnTermination As Integer = &H1D
        ' value for BreakOnTermination (flag)
        Process.EnterDebugMode()
        'acquire Debug Privileges
        ' setting the BreakOnTermination = 1 for the current process
        NtSetInformationProcess(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, BreakOnTermination, isCritical, 4)
    End Sub
End Class
```